# Symfony подписаться на все ошибки

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony5

пробую согласно доке

https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html

config/services.yaml

```
services:
    App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

в src/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface as EventSubscriberInterfaceAlias;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class ExceptionListener implements EventSubscriberInterfaceAlias
{
    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        dd($event);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => ['onKernelException', 20],
        ];
    }
}
```

но не срабатывает

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "debugMessage": "An unknown error occurred.",
      "message": "Internal server Error",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "internal"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 1
        }
      ],
```

вывод  php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.exception

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так у вас конфигурация не совпадает с той что прописана в документации

Comment: сори, скопировал старый код. сейчас так же

Comment: А проверьте зарегистрирован ли он у вас `php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/okMZ7pn.png видимо в этом проблема

Comment: Попробуйте задать тег `priority` и укажите например максимальное значение 255

Comment: вижу в списке первым, но в onKernelException не заходит

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101968/discussion-between-alpha-and-des1roer).

Comment: Говорите про listener, а по факту Subscriber.